# Continuous function and Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I've spent many time working on an interesting problem. However, I've not been able to solve it. The problem says: Build, if possible, a function function g ∈ L1 ([0, 1]) so that g is not bounded in any environment of any x ∈ [0,1] . In case the above is possible, deduct if it is possible to make the construction so that the exact value of ∫(between 0 and 1)gdx. I hope someone knows the answer

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a function $g$ with that property such that $\int_0^1g(x)dx=k$ for any $k\in\mathbb R$. Since every rational number can be expressed uniquely as $p/q$ such that $gcd(p,q)=1$, let $$g(x)=\begin{cases} q&\text{if}& x=p/q\\
k&\text{if}&x\in\mathbb [0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q
\end{cases}$$
Since $\lambda(\mathbb Q)=0$ you have that $\int_0^1g(x)dx=k$, now take $(a,b)\subset[0,1]$ and take $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $2^{n_0}< b-a$, so for any $n>n_0$ there exists $p_n$ such that $\frac{p_n}{2^n},\frac{p_n+1}{2^n}\in(a,b)$ since $p_n$ is odd or $p_n+1$ is odd you have that $gcd(p_n,2^n)=1$ or $gcd(p_n+1,2^n)=1$ so for any $n>n_0$ there exists $x\in(a,b)$ such that $g(x)=2^n$ and this clearly implies that $g$ is unbounded in $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

One such example could be $g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$g(x) := \begin{cases} q &, \text{ if $x=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)=1$} \\ 0 &, \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

This is unbounded in the neighborhood of any $x \in [0,1]$, but since the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ form a set of Lebesgue-measure $0$, we get that
$$\int_0^1 g(x) \: dx = 0$$